data labels in stacked Column chart in powerbi
I have stacked column chart with more than 7 legend, when I turn on the detail label title its only showing for 2 biggest contributors in the column and somewhere where all values are small its not showing data label for any of the legend values. I want the stacked column to show data label title for the top 3 values in stacked column. how should I do that. thanks in advance
I don't know how to put it manually


Can you put a screenshot of the chart?
